# Do While Loops, keeping track of user inputs Java

Tags: java, loops

How to I keep track of user input and pick out the largest and smallest? I am also not allowed to put arrays in the code so I need if statements. I have tried nesting if statements put I don't know how to compare numbers the user inputs when it's constantly changing. I have been able to print some results but it usually ends up with the last number I've entered as the output. Some help will be greatly appreciated.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double sum = 0;
    int totalnumber = 0;
    double avg = 0;
    double input;
    double num = 0;
    double large = 0;
    double small = 0;

    do{
        System.out.println("Please type in a number. Type 0 to quit.");
        input = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();



        if(input == 0)
        {
            break; //breaks the loop when the user enters 0
        }
        else
        {
            totalnumber += 1; //tracker for how many times user enters a number
            sum+= input; //get the sum of the entered inputs
            //large = input;
            //small = input;
            //num = input;


        }
    }while(true);


    avg = sum / totalnumber; //getting the average of the inputs

    if(totalnumber == 0) //if the user only put in 0
    {
        System.out.println("You didn't type anything in.");
    }
    else //if the user entered 1 or more numbersk
    {
        System.out.println("The sum of your inputs is: " + sum);
        System.out.println("The total number of inputs you provided was: " + totalnumber);
        System.out.println("The average of your inputs is: " + avg);
        System.out.println("The highest number you input was: " + large);
        //System.out.println("The lowest number you input was: " + small);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't make more work for people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0" "="), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Math.max` and `Math.min` methods.

before doing so, set the values as

```
int large = Math.MIN_VALUE;
int small = Math.MAX_VALUE;
// above do not need to be doubles

{
    totalnumber += 1; //tracker for how many times user enters a number
    sum+= input; //get the sum of the entered inputs
    large = Math.max (large, input);
    small = Math.min (small, input);
}
```